# Doxygen silently fails when function contains // (double-forward-slash) within a string in C#

Tags: c#, doxygen

When using Doxygen to generate documentation for C# code, the following code causes the rest of the .cs file to be ignored, and no error message is displayed to explain why:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the style sheet link.
/// </summary>
/// <value></value>
public string StyleSheetLink
{
    get { return "<link rel=\"STYLESHEET\" href=\"http://" + this.Request.Url.Authority + this.ThemesPath + "theme.css\">"; }
}
```

<s>I'm assuming that it's failing because the return string includes some XML-style content, which Doxygen is incorrectly parsing as comment XML and then failing miserably because the XML-that-isn't-actually-XML is - lo and behold - invalid XML.</s>

**Edit:** What appears to be happening is that the `//` part of the `http://` seems to be the problem. I changed that to `"http:/"+"/"` and it now runs through completely.

So, my updated question is **How do I force doxygen to ignore `//` within strings in the code?** <s>How do I make Doxygen ignore the string which happens to include XML-style content?</s> I just happened across this specific file, but with hundreds of possible classes to look at, it's very likely that there are a few more places where this occurs, so an automated approach (a flag in the expert settings maybe?) is preferred.